# How to access Kubernetes service through its name?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm running Cassandra cluster, which I want to access from the client running in the same cluster through service. After installing Cassandra helm chart using my pods and services look like this:

```
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/cassandra-0                      1/1     Running   0          10m

NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                        AGE
service/cassandra               ClusterIP      10.97.169.106   <none>        9042/TCP,9160/TCP,8080/TCP                     10m
service/cassandra-headless      ClusterIP      None            <none>        7000/TCP,7001/TCP,7199/TCP,9042/TCP,9160/TCP   10m
```

and I'm informd that Cassandra can be accessed through cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local:9042 from within the cluster.

After applying configmap, which looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cassandra-configmap
data:
  database_address: cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
```

and db client deployment file, which looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cassandra-web
  labels:
    app: cassandra-web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cassandra-web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cassandra-web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cassandra-web
        image: metavige/cassandra-web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9042
        env:
        - name: CASSANDRA_HOST
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: cassandra-configmap
              key: database_address
        - name: CASSANDRA_USER
          value: cassandra
        - name: CASSANDRA_PASSWORD
          value: somePassword
```

The problem is my client can't translate service name to address and is unable to connect to the database, saying `IPAddr::InvalidAddressError: invalid address`. If I replace `cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local` with `10.97.169.106`, everything works great, so there has to be some problem in resolving names.
I tried to run busybox, which looks OK.

```
$kubectl create -f https://k8s.io/examples/admin/dns/busybox.yaml
$kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup cassandra.default

Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 10.97.169.106 cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: Is your client running in the cluster? Is it expecting an IP address instead of a hostname?

Comment: Yes, my client is running in the cluster. I was assuming that the client doesn't receive the hostname, but rather the IP address from `Endopoints` key from the Service described by the hostname. If I'm mistaken, is there a way to translate hostname into IP address in case the clients can handle only IP address?

Comment: There should already be an environment variable for your pod, CASSANDRA_PORT_<Port>_TCP_ADDR, you can get the IP from that

Comment: I was able to use env variable to address the service, so thank you! I'm still curious why my initial approach didn't work .and how to solve the issue through host, so I'm leaving the question open for now

Comment: Looks like your client needs the IP address. Your first solution does not work because your configmap has hostname in it, not IP.

Comment: Why do you want to use hostname inside your deploy instead of IP address?

Comment: I wanted to have decoupled config values from deployment, that's why I wanted to use configMap.I can only store hostnames in configMap since I don't know the IP address of the service during the deployment. This strategy woked in this example https://gitlab.com/nanuchi/youtube-tutorial-series/-/tree/master/demo-kubernetes-components